# Draggable object hides outside content when wrapt in span

Tags: jquery, css, draggable, html

I have a simple CSS problem

In this site <strike>http://web.cinaird.se/pdf/test.htm</strike> (<--removed) I have a draggable images in the top content, I want a span that float on top  of the image and for this I need a span containing the image and a span floating on top.  So long no problem but now when i drag the image it hides outside the top content.

so my question is as follows, how can I wrap a image and a floating span above and still be able to drag it outside the container.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to change

```
function setDraggable(){
    $("#topContent img").draggable({
        opacity: 0.7,

        revert: 'invalid',
        helper: 'clone',
    });
}
```

to

```
function setDraggable(){
    $("#topContent img").draggable({
        opacity: 0.7,
        appendTo: 'body',
        revert: 'invalid',
        helper: 'clone',
    });
}
```

so the element's parent container will be the body